# How to join two tables using a third table when NULLS are involved

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, outer-join, join

I have two time card tables that I need to join. The two tables should be joined by the week ID, and employee resource code if applicable. However, with the exception of one week, the data that the two tables contain is from *different time frames* (i.e. in most cases there will not be matching data in both tables).

The first table (dt5) has that week’s ID, the employee's resource code, that employee's capacity for that week, and their actual hours worked for that week.

**dt5:**

```
+---------------+---------------+----------+---------------+
| id            | Resource_code | capacity | time_reported |
+---------------+---------------+----------+---------------+
|             1 |           555 |       40 |            40 |
|             1 |           333 |       25 |            20 |
|             2 |           555 |       40 |            40 |
|             2 |           333 |       25 |            20 |
|             3 |           555 |       40 |            40 |
|             3 |           333 |       25 |            20 |
|             4 |           555 |       40 |            39 |
|             4 |           333 |       25 |            24 |
+---------------+---------------+----------+---------------+
```

The second table (dt4) has the week’s ID, the employee's resource code, and the employee's planned hours for that week.

**dt4:**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id            | Resource_code | planned_hours |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|             4 |           555 |            30 |
|             4 |           333 |            20 | 
|             5 |           555 |            30 |
|             5 |           333 |            20 |
|             6 |           555 |            30 |
|             6 |           333 |            20 | 
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

When an employee completes their time card, the planned hours data is removed; before this occurs, there is a short period of time when the data overlaps (when both tables have data for the same period, like period 4 in my example tables). Because the two tables will only have one period in common at any given time, I am using a third table (gtd) that contains each week's ID to help join them.

**gtd:**

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | start_date | end_date |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |         10 |       20 |
|  2 |         30 |       40 |
|  3 |         50 |       60 |
|  4 |         70 |       80 |
|  5 |         90 |      100 |
|  6 |        110 |      120 |
|  7 |        130 |      140 |
|  8 |        150 |      160 |
|  9 |        170 |      180 |
| 10 |        190 |      200 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

- dates changed to integers in this example for simplification

**My result should look like this:**

Note that the week 4 rows contain data from both dt4 and dt5 (capacity, time reported, planned hours), because week 4 is the only overlapping week.

```
+----+---------------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id | Resource_code | capacity | time_reported | Resource_code | planned_hours |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  1 | 555           | 40       | 40            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  1 | 333           | 25       | 20            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  2 | 555           | 40       | 40            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  2 | 333           | 25       | 20            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  3 | 555           | 40       | 40            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  3 | 333           | 25       | 20            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  4 | 555           | 40       | 39            | 555           | 30            |
|  4 | 333           | 25       | 24            | 333           | 20            |
|  5 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 555           | 30            |
|  5 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 333           | 20            |
|  6 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 555           | 30            |
|  6 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 333           | 20            |
|  7 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
|  8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
|  9 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
| 10 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Here is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  gtd.id,   
  dt5.resource_code,    
  dt5.capacity, 
  dt5.time_reported,    
  dt4.resource_code,    
  dt4.planned_hours
FROM gtd
  LEFT JOIN dt5 ON gtd.id = dt5.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dt4 ON gtd.id = dt4.id
```

**My (incorrect) results are shown below:**

The errors are occurring in the week 4 rows. In two of the week 4 rows, the resource code and planned hours information from dt4 does not match up with the resource code from dt5.

```
+----+---------------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id | resource_code | capacity | time_reported | resource_code | planned_hours |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  1 | 555           | 40       | 40            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  1 | 333           | 25       | 20            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  2 | 555           | 40       | 40            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  2 | 333           | 25       | 20            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  3 | 555           | 40       | 40            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  3 | 333           | 25       | 20            | NULL          | NULL          |
|  4 | 555           | 40       | 39            | 555 (Correct) | 30            |
|  4 | 555           | 40       | 39            | 333 (Wrong)   | 20            |
|  4 | 333           | 25       | 24            | 555 (Wrong)   | 30            |
|  4 | 333           | 25       | 24            | 333 (Correct) | 20            |
|  5 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 555           | 30            |
|  5 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 333           | 20            |
|  6 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 555           | 30            |
|  6 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | 333           | 20            |
|  7 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
|  8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
|  9 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
| 10 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Based off my research, I think that I am either incorrectly using JOINS, or that I need a CASE statement somewhere. I’ve also tried joining the tables on resource code, but that eliminated a lot of my data. Any solutions or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

I am using tsql.

*Edited my question to fix inconsistencies with the column names (period_number changed to id)

Comment: Your tables don't really match the descriptions that you gave. As a quick guess try: LEFT OUTER JOIN dt4 ON gtd.period_number = dt4.period_number

Comment: How do you know which is the time card completed?

Comment: Is there any order field?

Comment: @Chuck, thank you for pointing that out. I've edited my question to clarify and to fix any inconsistencies.

Comment: @McNets, That week's time card is complete when an employee only has data for that specified week in dt5 (the table with the time_reported) column. 

If the employee has data for that specified week in both dt5 and dt4, then the time card is in an "in process" sort of stage. 

If the employee only has data for that specified week in dt4 (the table with planned_hours), then they have not submitted a time card yet.

I apologize, but I'm not sure what you mean by an order field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no doubt a simpler and more elegant solution that my answer, but since I'm very tired here's a brute force approach:

Use `UNION` to mash the two tables together. You'll need to manufacture dummy information that is only present in one table (such as `Capacity`).

Take the combined table and organise the data using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT f1.Period, f1.RC, f1.PlanTime, f1.ActTime
FROM
(SELECT  
  dt5.period_number AS 'Period',
  dt5.resource_code AS 'RC',    
  dt5.capacity AS 'ActCap', 
  0 AS 'PlanTime',
  dt5.time_reported AS 'ActTime'
FROM dt5
UNION ALL
SELECT  
  dt4.period_number AS 'Period',
  dt4.resource_code AS 'RC',    
  0 AS 'ActCap', 
  dt4.planned_hours AS 'PlanTime',
  0 AS 'ActTime'
FROM dt4) AS f1
GROUP BY f1.Period, f1.RC
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need the gtd table. Please try and see if this work for you. Please correct me if my understanding of your request is incorrect.

```
SELECT COALESCE(dt5.period_number, dt4.period_number) AS period_number,
    dt5.Resource_code,
    dt5.capacity,
    dt5.time_reported,
    dt4.Resource_code,
    dt4.planned_hours
FROM dt5
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dt4 a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dt5 b
            WHERE b.period_number = a.period_number
                AND b.Resource_code = a.Resource_code
            )
    ) dt4
    ON dt5.period_number = dt4.period_number
        AND dt4.Resource_code = dt5.Resource_code
ORDER BY COALESCE(dt5.period_number, dt4.period_number) ASC
```

### Test Data

```
;WITH cte_dt5(period_number,Resource_code,capacity,time_reported) AS 
(
SELECT 1, 555, 40, 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 333, 25, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 555, 40, 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 333, 25, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 555, 40, 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 333, 25, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 555, 40, 39 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 333, 25, 24
)
,cte_dt4 (period_number, Resource_code, planned_hours) AS
(
SELECT 4, 555, 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 333, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 555, 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 333, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 555, 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 333, 20
)
SELECT COALESCE(dt5.period_number, dt4.period_number) AS period_number,
    dt5.Resource_code,
    dt5.capacity,
    dt5.time_reported,
    dt4.Resource_code,
    dt4.planned_hours
FROM cte_dt5 AS dt5
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte_dt4 a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM cte_dt5 b
            WHERE b.period_number = a.period_number
                AND b.Resource_code = a.Resource_code
            )
    ) dt4
    ON dt5.period_number = dt4.period_number
        AND dt4.Resource_code = dt5.Resource_code
ORDER BY COALESCE(dt5.period_number, dt4.period_number) ASC
```

### Result

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|period_number|Resource_code|capacity   |time_reported|Resource_code|planned_hours|
+-------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|-------------|-------------+
|1            |555          |40         |40           |NULL         |NULL         |
|1            |333          |25         |20           |NULL         |NULL         |
|2            |555          |40         |40           |NULL         |NULL         |
|2            |333          |25         |20           |NULL         |NULL         |
|3            |555          |40         |40           |NULL         |NULL         |
|3            |333          |25         |20           |NULL         |NULL         |
|4            |555          |40         |39           |NULL         |NULL         |
|4            |333          |25         |24           |NULL         |NULL         |
|5            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |333          |20           |
|5            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |555          |30           |
|6            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |333          |20           |
|6            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |555          |30           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Code changes as per OP's request below. Commenting the Exist clause will give the result desired.

> user7571220: Thank you for your help! Everything is correct except for
>   the planned hours and resource code (which come from dt4) in week 4. I
>   am trying to include data from both tables in the week that they
>   overlap (week 4). I'm essentially trying to get the data for week 4 to
>   look like the comments I've posted below.
>
> | 4 | 555 | 40 | 39 | 555 | 30 |
>
> | 4 | 333 | 25 | 24 | 333 | 20 |

```
SELECT COALESCE(dt5.period_number, dt4.period_number) AS period_number,
        dt5.Resource_code,
        dt5.capacity,
        dt5.time_reported,
        dt4.Resource_code,
        dt4.planned_hours
    FROM cte_dt5 AS dt5
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM cte_dt4 a
        --WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        --        SELECT 1
        --        FROM cte_dt5 b
        --        WHERE b.period_number = a.period_number
        --            AND b.Resource_code = a.Resource_code
        --        )
        ) dt4
        ON dt5.period_number = dt4.period_number
            AND dt4.Resource_code = dt5.Resource_code
    ORDER BY COALESCE(dt5.period_number, dt4.period_number) ASC
```

### Result

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|period_number|Resource_code|capacity   |time_reported|Resource_code|planned_hours|
+-------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|-------------|-------------+
|1            |555          |40         |40           |NULL         |NULL         |
|1            |333          |25         |20           |NULL         |NULL         |
|2            |555          |40         |40           |NULL         |NULL         |
|2            |333          |25         |20           |NULL         |NULL         |
|3            |555          |40         |40           |NULL         |NULL         |
|3            |333          |25         |20           |NULL         |NULL         |
|4            |555          |40         |39           |555          |30           |
|4            |333          |25         |24           |333          |20           |
|5            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |333          |20           |
|5            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |555          |30           |
|6            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |333          |20           |
|6            |NULL         |NULL       |NULL         |555          |30           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Everything is correct except for the planned hours and resource code (which come from dt4) in week 4. I am trying to include data from both tables in the week that they overlap (week 4). I'm essentially trying to get the data for week 4 to look like the comments I've posted below.

Comment: |  4 | 555 | 40  | 39   | 555  | 30  |

Comment: |  4 | 333 | 25  | 24   | 333  | 20  |

Comment: Just comment the not exists clause should give you the result you are looking for @user7571220